# Remove page numbers from marrangeGrob (or arrangeList) pdf

Tags: r, gridextra

`marrangeGrob` in the `gridExtra` arranges grobs (usually ggplots in my case) in rows, columns and pages.  It also numbers the pages.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
require(gridExtra)

p <- function(plotdata) {
    x <- ggplot(plotdata, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        ggtitle(plotdata$gear[1])
    return(x)
}

all <- dlply(mtcars, .(gear), p)

allarranged <- do.call(marrangeGrob, c(all, nrow=1, ncol=2))
ggsave("multipage.pdf", allarranged, width=12)
```

That's a silly but reproducible example.

Now inspect the output of `str(allarranged[[1]])` to reveal the objects of the page numbers.  Reduced to the essentials, they're here:

```
[[1]]
  $ children     :List of 5
  ..$GRID.frame.1925:List of 6
  .. ..$ children     :List of 5
  .. .. ..$ GRID.cellGrob.1927:List of 10
  .. .. .. ..$ children     :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ GRID.text.1845:List of 11
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ label        : chr "page 1 of 2"
```

I made up the first few lines there because I'm having trouble writing the output of `str()` to file.  The point stands, though.  `$label` is the problem-child of many grandparents.  There are also several `$label`s per `arrangelist` (`arrangeList` is the output class of `arrangeGrob`).

Once you've figured out where the `$label`s are, then this works:
    allarranged[[1]]$children$GRID.frame.1770$children$GRID.cellGrob.1772$children$GRID.text.1690$label <- NULL

But how to predict that whole tree, or recurse through it looking for `$label`s?  If that weren't such an interesting problem I'd probably just contact the gridExtra maintainer.

Comment: Thanks @baptiste, package maintainer!  How could I have worked that out on my own?

Comment: The usage section of the doc page is a good hint here

Comment: Sorry @baptiste, somehow missed that.  I think I must have scanned down the list of arguments and followed the links to arrangeGrob where they're not actually defined.

Comment: it's sketchy alright :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `top=NULL` to `marrangeGrob`.

```
all <- dlply(mtcars, .(gear), p)

allarranged <- do.call(marrangeGrob, c(all, nrow=1, ncol=2, list(top=NULL) ))
ggsave("multipage.pdf", allarranged, width=12)
```