# Page number position using marrangeGrob and ggsave in R

Tags: r, gridextra

This is a trivial question, but one I would still like to solve. I am using `marrangeGrob` and `ggsave` to export a series of graphs. I would like to change the default position of the page numbers produced with `marrangeGrob`, from the top of the page to bottom right.

Based on this question; [Remove page numbers from marrangeGrob (or arrangeList) pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887758/remove-page-numbers-from-marrangegrob-or-arrangelist-pdf), I can include the arguments `top = NULL, bottom = quote(paste("page", g, "of", pages))` to shift the page number to the bottom of each page, but the page number is still in the centre.

I could add a lot of space to the start of the `paste` statement, thus: `"         page"` but that looks really ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Sample data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Create some plots
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
p2 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars) + ggtitle("title")
p3 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars, geom = "dotplot")

# Combine into a list, and change where page numbers will appear
Export <- marrangeGrob(list(p1, p2, p3), nrow = 2, ncol = 1, top = NULL, 
               bottom = quote(paste("page", g, "of", npages)))

# Export to a pdf file
ggsave(filename = "multipage.pdf", Export, width = 7, height = 10, units = "in")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a grob rather than a string,

```
bottom = quote(grid::textGrob(paste("page", g, "of", npages), x=1, hjust=1))
```

Comment: Thanks, works nicely. I modified the call slightly so that the text isn't jammed right into the edge of the page; `x = 0.9, vjust = -0.2`

Comment: Works great! Note, in order to change the font size, gp must be used: ```vjust=-0.2, gp = gpar(fontsize = 9)```